# multiple child records in a single row by join

Tags: mysql, join

I have one master table (teacher) structured like

```
teacherId   Name        Class
1       Praveen     10
2       John        9
```

and having a child table (student) structured like

```
studentId   teacherId   Name
1       1       David
2       1       Creg
3       2       Mike
4       2       Steve
5       2       Jim
```

How I can get a result set like

```
teacherId   teacher     studentId_1 student_1   studentId_2 student_2   studentId_3 student_3

1       Praveen     1       David       2       Creg        null        null
2       John        3       Mike        4       Steve       5       Jim
```

Thanks in advance..

Regards, 
Praveen

Comment: This is not something along the lines of how SQL is to be used! What would happen, if a teacher had 65536 students for example? You should use a normal query, with a single join, then from your application, aggregate the students under the teachers. The query: `SELECT t.teacherId, t.Name, s.studentId, s.Name FROM teacher t JOIN student s ON t.teacherId=student.teacherId`

Comment: Currently we are having 5 to 10 child. Our requirement is to show n number(let us say 3 for now) of row records need to come as columns